# LinkedBlockingQueue$Node.next on a null object reference

Tags: android

Help! Huawei mobile phone recently found the following Exception, there is a solution? Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBptp.png)

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$Node java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue$Node.next' on a null object reference
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.dequeue(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:184)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:415)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming-related problem/question.

Comment: To clarify, there is likely nothing you could do as a _developer_. Looks like proprietary OS/software problem.

Comment: @Hexfire Thanks , I will go to the OS for help